# html design messed up after ajax call response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on single page application, using many ajax calls for retrieving and storing data....
I am also using `.show()` and `.hide()` methods to make page user friendly....
 As can be seen, two divs participating in hide and show

Every function works fine, every ajax call is accordingly correct....
design messed up after last call i will describe at last of my question...

**Html**

```
<section class="block remove-top" id="contact-us" style="display: none;">
 <div id="message"></div>
 <form method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="selectedPackage"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
  <label>Email *</label>
  <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Your Email" />
  <div id="emailCkh" style="font-size: medium; font-weight: normal; color: red;"></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
   <label>Password *</label>
   <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="input-style" placeholder="Enter Password" />
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12">
   <label>Confirm Password *</label>
   <input name="confirmpassword" type="password" id="confirmpassword" class="input-style" placeholder="re-enter password" />
   <div id="pass" style="font-size:medium;font-weight:normal;color:red;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>

<section class="block remove-top" id="SecondInfo" style="display: none;">
</section>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var pkg = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["Package"]'
        data = $('#password').val();
    var len = data.length;   
    if(len < 1) {
        $("#pass").html("Password cannot be empty");
        event.preventDefault();
    }    
    else if($('#password').val() != $('#confirmpassword').val()) {
        $("#pass").html("Password should match");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        var Email = $('#Email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
            dataType: "JSon",
            data: {"Email": Email, "password": password},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "success") {
                    if (pkg == 5) {
                        $('#contact-us').hide();
                        $('#scc').show();
                        $('contact-us').animate({ scrollTop: $('#scc').offset().top }, 'slow');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#contact-us').hide();
                        $('#SecondInfo').show();
                        $('contact-us').animate({ scrollTop: $('#SecondInfo').offset().top }, 'slow');
                    }
                }
                else if (data == "fail") {
                    $("#emailCkh").html("Email Exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#emailCkh").html("Server Error");
                }
            },
            error: function (data, jqXHR, exception) {
                //some errors defined
            }
            });
    }
        });   
</script>
```

Sorry for posting most of my code although i have shorten it. The problem is occurred when `{ data == "fail" }` portion called.... It will update the div which wil tell user that he has entered the email which is already in db, try another.... Div updated successfully and after 2,3 seconds whole html messesd up....

What can be the cause or causes....any idea...?

Some screenshots for better look(browser zoom out for full view)...

before
[image: before ajax call]

after
[image: after ajax call]

[image]

Comment: try using a label for emailckh and setting .text instead of .html

Comment: thanks for reply everyone....nah, no console error

Comment: @JeremyC. thanks for reply, i tried label and every other possible thing like alert but issue remains.....

Comment: this probably isn't going to change anything but you might want to move $('#contact-us').hide(); outside of the if/else (it's being done anyways) always better to not have double code if avoidable

Comment: Also I don't really get what you mean by this: $('contact-us').animate is it possible that it's supposed to be $('#contact-us').animate ? Unless there is an html element called contact-us I haven't heard about before

Comment: i don't quite understand what you asking, but let me assure you sir ,,, every thing works fine but the last call on "fail" return....there is a section "contact-us"...and yes i have mistake of # selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running through your code I saw some irregularities, not sure if they will fix your problem but might be worth a try, after fixing what I think might be bugs I come up with this code:

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        var pkg = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["Package"]'
        data = $('#password').val();
    var len = data.length;   
    if(len < 1) {
        $("#pass").html("Password cannot be empty");
        event.preventDefault();
    }    
    else if($('#password').val() != $('#confirmpassword').val()) {
        $("#pass").html("Password should match");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        var Email = $('#Email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
            dataType: "JSon",
            data: {"Email": Email, "password": password},
            success: function (data) {                    
                if (data == "success") {
                    $('#contact-us').hide();
                    if (pkg == 5) {                            
                        $('#scc').show();
                        $('#contact-us').animate({ scrollTop: $('#scc').offset().top }, 'slow');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#SecondInfo').show();
                        $('#contact-us').animate({ scrollTop: $('#SecondInfo').offset().top }, 'slow');
                    }
                }
                else if (data == "fail") {
                    $("#emailCkh").html("Email Exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#emailCkh").html("Server Error");
                }
            },
            error: function (data, jqXHR, exception) {
                //some errors defined
            }
            });
    }
 });   
</script>
```

Don't pay any attention to the bad formatting.

What I did:

Added event variable in the click function (for event.preventDefault(), not even sure if it's necessary but it looks cleanr and better readable imo)
Put your $('#contact-us').hide(); outside of the if/else seeing as it was being called in both the if block and else block
Changed $('contact-us').animate() to $('#contact-us').animate()

Comment: thanks for answer man, +1 for effort, i will accept after trying surely

Comment: could you take some before and after screenshots of your page? so I can see what is wrong exactly

Comment: after retesting, i have found that their is some duplicated divs were created after ajax response....should i share screen shots???

Comment: yeah sure, won't hurt to share those, someone might see something on them

Comment: some time it gives error prevent this page for creating additional dialogues